# onclick image and toggle div using javascript not work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

onclick image and toggle div using javascript not work ?

i change from

```
    <input type="button" id="Showdiv1" name="Showdiv1" value="Show Div 1" onclick="showDiv('div1')" />
```

to

```
<img src="https://developer.apple.com/homekit/images/homekit-hero.png" onclick="showDiv('div1')" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a3MKG/36/

```
<script>
function showDiv(id) {    
  $("#div1").toggle();
}   

$(document).click(function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).closest('#div1, input[name="Showdiv1"]').length) 
    {
        $('#div1').hide()
    }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID to your image (below is IMGClick) and change your script to the following :

```
$("#IMGClick").click(function(){
$("#div1").toggle();
} );
```